# Is there a specific drawing order in PCL?

Tags: printer-control-language

I am trying to write a PCL document, which has several drawing objects (lines, rectangles, texts...)

I found that if I draw the rectangles before anything else, they appear in the right position and size. However, if I draw them among the rest of objects, they are drawn smaller and in the wrong place.

The PCL seems to be OK (although this is yet to be proven), but it has made me think that perhaps graphic objects must be drawn in a particular order (I am using HPGL/2, by the way).

Does someone know if this is so? I have not been able to find anything in the PCL Manual nor in the internet (which leads me to believe that there is not such drawing order).

Comment: Can you post some code? You have probably written position or scale commands that unintentionally affect your rectangles.

Comment: @ErikOlson You are right. After reviewing the code with the help of a much more experienced partner, we could detects lots of unnecessary `SC` commands that were resetting the HPGL/2 environment. When we removed them, everything worked fine. Thank you very much! If you post your comment as an answer, I'll be glad to mark it as final, and close the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you have written position or scale commands that unintentionally affect your rectangles.